# Paypal return url with Angular app

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, paypal

This is part of my router.js:

```
  .state('app.thanks', {
        url: "/thanks",
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/thanks.php"
          }
        }
      })
```

and in payapl WEBSITE PAYMENT PREFERENCES -> return url address I define this: 
https://my-website-url.com/#/app/thanks,

as I understand, in order to get the params from Payapl I need to use this code to get transaction id:

```
if(isset($_GET['tx']) && ($_GET['tx'])!=null && ($_GET['tx'])!= "") {
    $tx = $_GET['tx'];
    if($tx) doSometing();
}
else {
    exitCode();
}
```

How can I combine it with my angular app? only need to put this code in my thanks.php page?

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this step with your angular App.
This has to be very clear since you need to verify the Transaction and payment with Paypal. to do that properly, the code has to run on the server and validated the payment process was actually successful, otherwise you can just hand out your products for free. You did not add any code here to do that so I hope you have one ready that does it properly.

After verifying the Transaction on the server your own script can redirect the user to the right location on the angular app.
So your setup and script should be similar to this -

WEBSITE PAYMENT PREFERENCES ->  https://my-website-url.com/paypalVerify.php

```
if ( isset($_GET['tx']) && $_GET['tx'] ) {
    $tx = $_GET['tx'];
    if(verifyTx($tx)) {
        //do some stuff
        header('Location: https://my-website-url.com/#/app/thanks');
        die();
    }   
}
header('Location: https://my-website-url.com/#/app/wheresMyMoney');
die();
```